# Display attachment in LWC

Tags: html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

I'm trying to display a image stored in an attachment.
I have tried the following combinations and nothing seem to work:

````
<img src="'servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='{productItem.product.attachmentId}"/>
<img src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={productItem.product.attachmentId}"/>
<img src=\{imageDownload}{productItem.product.attachmentId}/> <!--(imageDownload = '/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=';)-->
<img src="'https://ccdev3-abinbev-ei-crm.cs105.force.com/MyABIB2BCommunity/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='+{productItem.product.attachmentId}"/>
<img src="'https://ccdev3-abinbev-ei-crm.cs105.force.com/MyABIB2BCommunity/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file='{productItem.product.attachmentId}"/>
<img src="https://ccdev3-abinbev-ei-crm.cs105.force.com/MyABIB2BCommunity/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={productItem.product.attachmentId}"/>```

Output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/6q8kt.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix the issue by changing the wrapper from an Id to a String with hard coded value:
Basically my wrapper now looks like
attachmentId: "https://ccdev3-abinbev-ei-crm.cs105.force.com/MyABIB2BCommunity/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=00P1w000003eSStEAM"

and in LWC HTML I simply use: